# Interpreting Network Data in IE9

Tags: performance, internet-explorer-9, ie-developer-tools

I'm trying to debug a performance problem in IE9, but have problems understanding what the developer tools try to tell me. I use IE because the problem does not appear in other browsers.

I see huge times categorized as "Start", i.e. before "Request" and "Response". Note that "Start" is the term used in my German version of the IE, I hope it is the same term in English as well.

"Start" takes about 2-20sec while the actual "Request" and "Response" are well below 100ms.

**What does the IE do during this time? What might be the reason for this?**

The receiving side of the requests (IBM Webseal) seems to see the requests only after the "Start" time has passed.

Some more background:

We have a little web application which has reasonable performance in most configurations. Authentication for the application is done through an IBM Webseal.

This just works for Firefox. This also works for IE9 when authenticated via username+password or RSA Token, but it is extremely slow when authentication happens based on PKI cards in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

In F12's network tool the times refer too:

Start - The time from when the request was initially created to when the request is sent. There can be a delay here if the max number of connections to a server is exceed at the request gets queued.
Request - Time to first byte. The time taken to send the request and receive the first response from the server.
Response - The time taken to receive the response data from the server.

If you go to the timings tab in the tool and click on any of the timings like 'start' you'll get a brief description of it in the bottom right.

Comment: I got the description, but I am still wondering what causes the delay. The connections shouldnt be a problem, since nothing else gets loaded.

Comment: Assuming the network request is caused by a HTML element. Is there much HTML for IE to parse before it finds the URL to download? Is there any <script> tags with code that executes? You can also look at the initiator tab and the value of the "Preparser ID". Essentially IE queues downloads in the order it finds them while parsing the document. However if it encounters a <script> tag it has to stop parsing and let the script execute as it can modify the document (document.write etc.). To counter this IE will spin up another parser, the lookahead parser, on a diff thread to look for URLs.

Comment: Is there more information on this lookahead parser somewhere on the inter nets?